# the need of use DB::commit twice in laravel to make transaction work

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to save some data in database using laravel beginTransaction() / DB::commit. The usual structure to do it is:

```
 DB::beginTransaction();
 try {

 // prepare data;
 // $data->save();

 DB::commit();

 } catch (\Exception $e) {
 DB::rollback();
 echo 'erro';
 }
```

Using the code above I do not get erro message and data is not saved, but if I use DB:commit twice like in :

```
DB::beginTransaction();
try {

// prepare data;
// $data->save();

DB::commit();
DB::commit();

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    DB::rollback();
    echo 'erro';
}
```

Everything works fine. Someone knows why this happend and if it is safe to do what I'm doing?

Solved

Code was writen inside a foreach, problem was the oppening of multiples transactions and was solved putting foreach inside transaction

```
DB::beginTransaction();
try {
foreach($data as d){
  // prepare data;
  // $data->save();
}
DB::commit();

} catch (\Exception $e) {
DB::rollback();
echo 'erro';
}
```

Comment: This piece of code is inside any loop? `for` `foreach` .. ? Or another transaction?

Comment: it is inside a foreach

Comment: You are probably openning multiple transactions. Could you share the entire code?

Comment: Could you use a single transaction wrapping your `foreach`? Or do you need some data to save and others to rollback in the operation?

Comment: Unhappily I can't share the code it self, but giving a more complete view I have:

    foreach(array_data as data){
    //verify if data is valid
        DB::beginTransaction();
        try {

        // prepare data;
        // $data->save();

        DB::commit();

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            DB::rollback();
            echo 'erro';
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Check `DB::transactionLevel()` prior to running beginTransaction.  It should be 0, if it's 1, you already have an active transaction.

Comment: I put the foreach inside begin transaction and it worked properly. So, the problem was the openning of multiples transactions?